# Invisible files in /tmp directory

Tags: perl, cgi, file-permissions, tmp

I have a CGI::Session script that writes the session id to the /tmp file. The script doesn't error out, but when I check the /tmp directory, I don't find the cgisess* file. This is the permission of /tmp:

```
info@linux-web-server [tmp]# ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 4096 Jul 31 00:00 /tmp
```

I added this command to the script:

```
my $userexecuting = getpwuid( $< );
Logger::debug("cgiscript: csv_auth : userexecuting : $userexecuting");
```

And this is the result:

```
2023-07-31 02:06:01 : cgiscript: csv_auth : userexecuting : www-data
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
chmod +t csvauth
chattr +i csvauth
```

The directory wasn't deleted but the file that is supposed to be there isn't there.

If I have cgi::session write the cgisess* file to my home directory then it works but I don't want to put the file in my home directory and I would like to understand why it is doing this.

I added this to script and the files showed up. So the files are there but I can't see them when I issue the `ls` command on a linux terminal:

```
 my @cgisessfiles = `ls -l /tmp/csvauth/*`;
    print "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
    print "<html>\n";
    foreach my $cgisessfile (@cgisessfiles) {
      print "<h3>$cgisessfile</h3>\n";
    }

-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 223 Jul 31 11:12 /tmp/csvauth/cgisess_23ad19ddc8f00f1a31dc72e54ea3205d
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 189 Jul 31 11:16 /tmp/csvauth/cgisess_38f7ae2b68e39f6a16a869517007b963
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 210 Jul 30 21:06 /tmp/csvauth/cgisess_3938ea95909e78e3e718edf45460c6b7
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 210 Jul 30 21:12 /tmp/csvauth/cgisess_3ab70e080cda071bcc061d8d63d6565c
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 187 Jul 30 16:39 /tmp/csvauth/cgisess_3e7a9e0b68ff69849ed43a1865f62f04
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 45140 Jul 31 10:57 /tmp/csvauth/csv_auth_log.txt
```

What do I need to do to make it work? The permissions seem to be correct.

Comment: You mentioned in a previous comment that you suspected that this is the effect of `PrivateTmp=yes` configuration option for systemd running the httpd service.. Have you checked this?

Comment: Are you using the Apache web server?

Comment: See also https://fluca1978.github.io/2018/04/19/ApacheSystemdPrivateTemp.html

Comment: @Håkon Hægland It worked. You should formalize it as an answer so I can give you credit. Also, do you know if there are any security issues relating to not setting privateTemp=yes? I read the article but I am not an IT specialist.

Comment: *"It worked. You should formalize it as an answer"* : Great, see my answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The script doesn't error out, but when I check the /tmp directory, I don't find the cgisess* file

This is because the cgi script is running with a private `/tmp` directory (see [systemd man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), under subsection `Sandboxing/PrivateTmp`). This private `/tmp` is not directly visible from outside the script, but see [this blog post](https://fluca1978.github.io/2018/04/19/ApacheSystemdPrivateTemp.html) for an example of how to locate the files.

> but I don't want to put the file in my home directory and I would like to understand why it is doing this.

You do not need to put the files somewhere else, as you also showed in your question the files do exist. If you really do need access to the temporary files written by the cgi script from the outside (for example for inspecting them from a terminal for debugging purposes) you could try to locate the real directory, which would be something like `/tmp/systemd-private-*-apache2.service-*` where the * are some kind of id as shown in the above linked blog post.

Comment: In /`var/tmp` there is this file systemd-private-28d027d4b2594a819a1538db5e502f1d-apache2.service-fPLBqj` but I can't access this directory even using sudo. How do I access it?

Comment: Hmm, so the private `tmp` is not in `/tmp`, but in `/var/tmp/` is that what you observe? Can you try run `sudo ls /var/tmp/systemd-private-28d027d4b2594a819a1538db5e502f1d-apache2.service-fPLBqj` ?

Comment: It is also in /tmp but I can't access it. I don't have permission.

Comment: I see it now. `sudo ls /tmp/systemd-private-28d027d4b2594a819a1538db5e502f1d-apache2.service-9RMMjj/tmp/csvauth
cgisess_c5161e1edd3b2c265e565c694cf98ee5`. So why is that more secure? It is just another directory in the systemd directory.

Comment: Maybe because other processes will use the standard `/tmp` (or their own private tmp) and then the probability of overwriting a file in your private `tmp` will be smaller?

Comment: I see the files but I can't delete them. Is that normal? info@linux-web-server [tmp]# `sudo ls -l systemd-private-28d027d4b2594a819a1538db5e502f1d-apache2.service-9RMMjj/tmp/csvauth`
`total 8`
`-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 223 Aug  2 21:26 cgisess_273748d0c754b4678a6f70949158063f`
`-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 224 Aug  2 21:24 cgisess_c5161e1edd3b2c265e565c694cf98ee5`

Comment: Why does it say command not found for "sudo cd" ? `info@linux-web-server [tmp]# sudo cd systemd-private-28d027d4b2594a819a1538db5e502f1d-apache2.service-9RMMjj/
sudo: cd: command not found`

Comment: I have to do sudo -s as explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/241129/why-wont-sudo-cd-work

Answer (score -1):

Is it bailing right at the point it tries to write? If you're on Linux, try strace.

There's a (faint) chance the session file gets deleted when the process finishes.

Comment: The script finishes so it doesn't bail out. How do I incorporate strace to the script? And if that's the case that the file is being deleted when the process finished, how do I prevent that?

Comment: If I have cgi:session (perl) write the file to my home directory, then the file is there upon completion.